# How to Run Specta Tests in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, testing, tdd

I am trying to unit test my code in Xcode using the Specta and Expecta frameworks. I have read numerous tutorials online, and have set up my file accordingly (see below). After setting it up, an empty diamond appears to the left of the SpecBegin(Services), which becomes a play button when hovering over.

After clicking the play button, I always receive the following output:

```
Test Suite 'All tests' started at 2014-06-13 16:34:54 +0000
Test Suite 'Handybook_podTests.xctest' started at 2014-06-13 16:34:54 +0000
Test Suite 'Handybook_podTests' started at 2014-06-13 16:34:54 +0000
Test Suite 'Handybook_podTests' finished at 2014-06-13 16:34:54 +0000.
Executed 0 tests, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.000 (0.000) seconds
Test Suite 'Handybook_podTests.xctest' finished at 2014-06-13 16:34:54 +0000.
Executed 0 tests, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.000 (0.000) seconds
Test Suite 'All tests' finished at 2014-06-13 16:34:54 +0000.
Executed 0 tests, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.000 (0.001) seconds
```

What exactly is being executed when I hit the play button? It seems like nothing I have written is being run. How do I run the code in my ServicesSpec.m file?

The file is below:

```
// ServicesSpec.m

#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>

#import <Specta/Specta.h>
#define EXP_SHORTHAND
#import <Expecta/Expecta.h>
#import "Services.h"

SpecBegin(Services)

describe(@"Services", ^{
    it(@"Should get the Most Common Services", ^AsyncBlock{
        [Services getMostCommonServices:^(id responseObject) {
            // a bunch of Expecta matchers/tests to check the responseObject

            NSLog(@"Most Common Services Tests Passed!");
            done();

        } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.userInfo);
            done();
        }];
    });
});

SpecEnd
```

Comment: Try with a simple non-AsyncBlock test. Does it change anything? Also are you using CocoaPods? - you may be missing a dependent library or framework otherwise. Finally, is the ServicesSpec part of the test project target?

Comment: @dB No, Yes, and Yes. I realized that I was using Specta version 0.1.11 as per the [Expecta github page](http://www.github.com/specta/expecta). I still don't know why the tests didn't run with that version. I updated my Podfile for Specta version 0.2.1, the latest version according to the [Specta github page](http://www.github.com/specta/specta), and now the tests run. Go figure